# confirming uniqueness of a PDE solution

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose the problem ${yu_x-xu_y=0}$, find all the solutions for the given conditions:

1. ${u(x,0)=x^{2}}$
2. ${u(x,1)=x^2+1}$
3. ${u(x,0)=x}$

where ${x}$ is a real number.

I solved the problem and reached the general solution given by ${u(x,y)=F(x^{2}+y^{2})}$

Applying the conditions gave me: ${u(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}}$ for the three conditions! But the question is, is it unique?

So checking the Jacobian for the three gives that:
${J = s}$ where it can be zero at one point only, I am stuck at finding the difference for the three cases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question about finding the difference for the three cases.

For the cases 1 and 2 you correctly find the solution 
$$u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$
Obviously this solution satisfies the PDE and the respective conditions. This would be the same for any condition such as $u(x,a)=x^2+a^2$ .

But this is different for case 3 :

Condition $u(x,0)=x=F(x^2+0^2)=F(x^2)$

Let $\quad x^2=X \quad;\quad x= \pm\sqrt{X}$

Putting this function $F(X)$ into the above general solution where $X=x^2+y^2$ gives : $u(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ and in order to satisfy the condition $u(x,0)=x$, the solution is :
$$u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } x>0 \\
-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } x<0 
\end{cases}$$